# Mail App doesn't let me login to my iCloud mail

Tags: pantheon-mail

I tried the settings given at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304 with an app specific password. But nothing seems to work out. 
I keep getting this error saying `Unable to validate: SMTP connection error`. What am I supposed to do ? I'm able to connect to my account via other email clients (eg. Outlook)

Answer (score 0):

After test I think I can add my iCloud mail with this settings

[image]

But after I have this

[image]

But I do not want to accept this message

I think it's better that you go through another mail tool that natively supports iCloud

Comment: The problem with the certificate is probably that you enter the IP, and the certificate is issued for the domain name, this it doesn't match. I would use the domain name.

Comment: yes that's exactly it, I tried all the possible combinations with domain name for SMTP and IMAp and it is only with the ip that it works, so it is not very secure

Comment: So far as I can tell the domain: `imap.mail.me.com` works for IMAP and `smtp.mail.me.com` for smtp. And then you might need to experiment with TLS, SSL and Start TLS

Answer (score 0):

I did it by installing Evolution and setting it with [this](https://webhostinghero.org/ubuntu-icloud-sync/)

Let it sets, then open Elementary Mail app and you'll find your iCloud mail account.
You'll just have to remove evolution and that's all.